# Set initial scale via javascript - Android not scaling out

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I've built a (semi) responsive site which goes down to a minimum width of 768pixels.  This is because the content isn't really practical for screens smaller than the iPad.

I have `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0" />`
in the head of the HTML and then a min-width set on the body in CSS.

However I would still like the site to look presentable on mobile devices such as the iPhone, Nexus etc.

What I have done is a little bit of JavaScript like this:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 480) {
            document
                .querySelector("meta[name=viewport]")
                .setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=0.4', 'maximum-scale=0.4', 'width=768');
        };
```

This works nicely on the iPhone, scaling out the site so that it fits in the viewport, and then the user can zoom in if they wish.

This same bit of code doesn't behave in the same way on Androids, instead the page loads zoomed right in to the top left corner, and the user would have to zoom out to view the whole page.

Does anybody have any ideas as to how this can be achieved on Android? Or is it a no-go?

Thanks

Comment: The meta tag works fine for me. What doesn't the meta tag actually do?

Comment: So on the iPhone it zooms the site out to the minimum width and you can see the whole page, on android it zooms in - is this just the default behaviour of the browser?

Comment: hmmm the more I look at it the more it seems browser specific.  the stock android browser works nicely, chrome for android and firefox for android both zoom the page in... ah well! don't think it can be done then

Comment: I think there may be a fix and it may be a meta tag also...

Comment: I do know that the Twitter Bootstrap responsive layout works on all Apple and Android devices, as well as Google Chrome on the desktop, Opera, and Firefox. Take a look at the code (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html).

Comment: Yeah i mean if the page was properly responsive then it would work fine, it's just the fact that i need the minimum width to be 768pixels which doesn't play nicely with mobiles... thanks for your help